# Azure CosmoDB deployment fails with "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

My template is this:

```
{
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "cosmosdbname": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "allowedIps": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "vnetName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "subnetName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "variables": {
        "subnetIdA": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
        "location": "[resourcegroup().location]"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
          "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
          "name": "[parameters('cosmosdbname')]",
          "location": "[variables('location')]",
          "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
          "properties": {
            "ipRangeFilter": "[parameters('allowedIps')]",
            "enableAutomaticFailover": false,
            "enableMultipleWriteLocations": false,
            "isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled": true,
            "virtualNetworkRules": [
              {
                "id": "[variables('subnetIdA')]"
              }
            ],
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
            "consistencyPolicy": {
              "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session",
              "maxIntervalInSeconds": 5,
              "maxStalenessPrefix": 100
            },
            "locations": [
              {
                "locationName": "[variables('location')]",
                "failoverPriority": 0
              }
            ],
            "capabilities": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I exported it from Azure and made some modifications. However, I just get the "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'." when trying to deploy it and cannot figure out what is wrong with the template.

Comment: Do you have permissions on the VNET you are trying to read? Is the `allowedIps` value a comma separated list with no spaces?

Comment: Yes I am owner on the vnet and yes the list is like that.

Comment: In my case it was the location problem, I changed the location and issue was gone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the virtualnetworkrules completely from my json and now it works.